# Set locale based on browser lang & users table value

Tags: laravel

I am trying to make some language options using Laravel.

I have a working solution where user can change language:

Http/Middleware/Localization.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Localization
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if ( \Session::has('locale')) {
            \App::setLocale(\Session::get('locale'));

            // You also can set the Carbon locale
            Carbon::setLocale(\Session::get('locale'));
        }   

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And the links:

```
<li><a href='locale/da'>Danish</a></li>
<li><a href='locale/en'>English</a></li>
```

This solution is working fine. However I would like to check for users browser language if not logged in, and check for language in users table field "lang" if user is logged in.

I think the solution should look something like this:
(i have implemeted this directly in view).

Not sure if I should implement it in config/app.php somehow, where the locale is set.

'locale' => 'en',

```
  @php
    // If user is logged in
    if (Auth::check())
    {
        // Get the user specific language
        $locale = Auth::user()->lang;

        // Set the language
        App::setLocale($locale);
    }
    else {

        $locale = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);

        if (!empty($locale)) {
            $locale == "en";
        }

        if ( \Session::has('locale')) {           
        } else{
            App::setLocale($locale);
        }
    }
@endphp
```

Comment: You can just add an `else` block in your `Localization` middleware, so when there is no session locale, get the preferred language from the request `\App::setLocale($request->getPreferredLanguage());`. And that should be enough.

Comment: Okay, it seems to return correct browser lang. but in format da_dk and I only want the da. 
Can something like this work ?
substr(\App::setLocale($request->getPreferredLanguage()), 0, 2);

Comment: also, how can I incorporate this part:
     // If user is logged in
         if (Auth::check())
         {
             // Get the user specific language
             $request = Auth::user()->lang;
     
             // Set the language
             App::setLocale($request);
         }